# Monotone convergence for $E(\sum_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|)=\sum_{k}E(|X_{n_{k}}|)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $n_{k}$ be such that $\sum_{k}E(|X_{n_{k}}|)<+\infty$,

In that case:
$$E\left(\sum_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|\right)=\sum_{k}E(|X_{n_{k}}|)<+\infty$$ (monotone convergence)

Therefore, $\sum_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|<+\infty$ almost surely.

It follows that:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}X_{n_{k}}=0$$ (as the general term of a convergent series).

How is monotone convergence used to demonstrate that, for a sequence $n_k$ such that $\sum_{k}E(|X_{n_{k}}|) < +\infty$, we can conclude that $E(\sum_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|) = \sum_{k}E(|X_{n_{k}}|)$, and how does this imply that the series $\sum_{k}|X_{n_{k}}|$ converges almost surely, leading to the conclusion $\lim_{n\to+\infty}X_{n_{k}} = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet$ Set
$$
     S_m = \sum_{k = 1}^m \vert X_{n_k}\vert
$$
Then $S_m \le S_{m + 1} \ \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $S_m \uparrow \sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert$. Now, using the monotone convergence theorem (or simply the Beppo Levi's theorem), we get
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert\right) = \sum_k \mathbb{E}\vert X_{n_k} \vert
$$

$\bullet$ If we further assume that $\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert\right) < \infty$. Then, $\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert < \infty$ almost surely. Indeed, if $\mathbb{P}(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert = \infty) > 0$, then
$$
     \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert\right) \ge \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert \cdot 1\{\sum_k\vert X_{n_k} \vert = \infty\}\right) = \infty \cdot \mathbb{P}(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert = \infty) = \infty
$$

$\bullet$ Finally, $\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert < \infty$ almost surely implies $X_{n_k} \rightarrow 0$ almost surely. This fact is purely from real analysis.
That is,
$$
      \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n < \infty \Longrightarrow \lim_n a_n = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you. How can I determine if it is a series with positive terms?

Comment: @IvanGozard Because $|X| \ge 0$ for all random variables $X$.

Comment: we have

$\lim_{m \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \vert X_{n_k} \vert = \sum_{k=1} \vert X_{n_k} \vert $

Upon applying Beppo Levi's theorem, I obtained the following result:

$\lim_{m \to +\infty} E\left(\sum_{k=1}^m \vert X_{n_k} \vert \right) = E\left(\lim_{m \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^m \vert X_{n_k} \vert \right) = E\left(\sum_{k=1} \vert X_{n_k} \vert \right)$

This seems to be different from the expression:

$\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_k \vert X_{n_k} \vert \right)=\sum_k \mathbb{E}\vert X_{n_k} \vert $

Can someone help me understand why these expressions differ?

Comment: @IvanGozard By linearity, $$ \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^m \vert X_{n_k}\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^m \mathbb{E}(\vert X_{n_k} \vert) \rightarrow \sum_k \mathbb{E}\vert X_{n_k} \vert $$ as $m$ tends to $\infty$